# Python regex search with greedy operator

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to find an expression, and here is what i am trying to do

```
import re
h1= open("test.txt")
for ln in h1:
    ln = ln.rstrip()
    if re.search("^From:.+@", ln):
        print(ln)
```

As per the logic it should stop the search at '@', however in my case that doesn't happen i get the following output:
From: ray@media.berkeley.edu

I also tried to use a qualifier '?' but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone suggest why it isn't working or how can i make it work specifically using regex.

Comment: What are you trying to get—what’s your expected output?

Comment: My expected output should be : "From: ray" , it should not go past beyond '@'

Comment: @Rookie111 Try this regex `From:[^@]+`

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately regex is an requirement.

Comment: From:[^@]+   Tried using this but it did not work. Still getting the same output.

Comment: re.search doesn’t modify ln, so when you are printing ln, you’re actually printing the entire ln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Regex` is the only thing which you are looking for, Then you can try something like this.

**Problems:**

> **1.** You should not print whole line.
>
> **2.** You should use `^From:[^@]+` to prevent matching of `@`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/866160)

```
import re
h1= open("test.txt")
for ln in h1:
    ln = ln.rstrip()
    result = re.search("^From:[^@]+", ln)
    if result is not None:
        print(result.group(0))
```

[**Try regex demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/bNAId5/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sahil Gulati, that worked! I am able to extract the expression.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the entire line, you can instead do:

```
print(ln.split('@')[0])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @salparadise 
Yes, that has worked for me before as well. However I wonder if this has changed from previous versions of python. Because the same code that I mentioned above has worked for me without me actually specifying the split() function when printing. So i guess this is the only way to get it to work?

Comment: @Rookie111 better ways to get this to work, see the regex and non-regex answers.

Comment: @Rookie111 check the above answer, I have provided with regex.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex solution:**

```
# regex = r"(.+?)@"

import re
h1= open("test.txt")
regex = r"(.+?)@"
for ln in h1:
    ln = ln.rstrip()
    matches = re.search(regex, ln)
    if matches:
        for groupNum in range(0, len(matches.groups())):
            groupNum = groupNum + 1
            print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = matches.start(groupNum), end = matches.end(groupNum), group = matches.group(groupNum)))
```

Other way by splitting and using startswith:

```
h1= open("test.txt")
for ln in h1:
    if ln.startswith("From: "):
        print(ln.split("@")[0])

# Output From: ray
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone.. It was really helpful. I have now got the regex working.